# MD5 Java Pattern

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I am following [BalusC's DAO Tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html), where there is this function:

```
private static String hashMD5IfNecessary(String password) {
    return !"^[a-f0-9]{32}$".matches(password) ? hashMD5(password) : password;
}
```

which I coupled with:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.password}" />
```

But `"^[a-f0-9]{32}$".matches(password)` (where `password` has been retrieved from a MySQL table) always returns `false`, even when it is passed an MD5-hashed password, like `21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3`.

I've also tried the following patterns:

- `[a-f0-9]{32}`
- `[a-f0-9]{32}+`

but they still always evaluate to `false`. Besides, I highly doubt that BalusC's original code is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: A method called `hashMD5IfNecessary`, with a parameter named `password`, is **very** evil!

Comment: Anyways, storing a simple, unsalted, MD5 hash of a password in a database is, nowadays, mostly the same as storing it in cleartext.

Comment: @BrunoReis Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for the input. I'm kind of newbish in security stuff. I thought MD5 was enough. You mean it is still hackable?

Comment: Certainly! Make a google search for "reverse md5" or "md5 lookup", or "md5 rainbow table", and you will see what I'm talking about. If you want to make it more difficult to obtain the clear-text password from the cipher-text, you should consider using some rounds of HMAC (with SHA1 or SHA256, not MD5). Also, if you could make the salt random and store it (or derive it from some other constant information of the user, or be sure to recalculate it and update the password whenever the user updates the information from which the salt is derived), you get bonus points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

the matches() method *takes* a regex as the parameter, so given what you've written in the question, it will always return false, as the password is unlikely to be a regex that matches "^[a-f0-9]{32}$".

Try

```
password.matches("^[a-f0-9]{32}$")
```

instead